# Good Textbook on Topology

Tags: analysis

I have one year calculus and one year linear algebra background. In addition, I have had one semester study in metric space analysis. Can anyone suggest some good textbooks on topology, please? A reader-friendly text with plenty of examples would be ideal. Thank you!

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Topology-2nd-Edition-James-Munkres/dp/0131816292

Comment: I can't understand this kind of questions: don't you people have a mathematics library in your school?! Then go there and dive into books **and check** and *then* you ask about several options you already checked! Perhaps this is a sign of our times: who has time for libraries now?

Comment: @DonAntonio So you want him to just copy paste the library catalog to you ? For someone who have no started on topology, obviously he cant decide which references are good....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly recommend [Munkres' *Topology*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131816292). It covers a lot of general topology in a very clear manner with quite a few examples, as well as covering some algebraic topology later in the book.

Comment: just now i have suggested same book :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert but I found munkres book hard to read when i started. He didn't quite give the "drive" to delve into the subject.

Then i found "[Introduction to topological manifolds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441979395)" by lee and i was hooked. The book talks a lot about manifolds which munkres hardly mentions. A lot of the problems are really interesting since manifolds are more intuitive then most of the other topological spaces.

After a finishing the first 5 chapters I felt I wasn't really grasping the subject but I had a lot of motivation to learn so I switched back and discovered it wasn’t as comprehensive as munkres so I started again with munkres.

The second ride is great so far. I'm now at chapter 5.

Although i learned some things twice I don't regret a thing. The books give a different view of the topic which I really benefited from.

All in all munkres is a great book as mentioned already if however you find that it is not "gripping" enough or too hard i would highly recommend lee's "introduction to topological manifolds".

(It might be relevant that I'm not enrolled in any university and learn entirely by myself using this wonderful site for help when I’m in need.)